# сгруппированные строки bootstrap в проектах ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc

Представление получает данные из модели `@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.Person>`, в модели определены поля такие как ФИО, Email, возраст, город и т.д.
Как сделать таблицу с группировкой строк по городам?
Вот что уже пытался сделать

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ФИО</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Возраст</th>
        <th>Данные1</th>
        <th>Данные3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Select(x => x.City).Distinct())
    {
        <tr>
            <td><strong>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item)</strong></td>
        </tr>
            foreach (var item1 in Model.Where(p=> p.City == item))
            {
                <tr>
                    @if (item2.organization == "Рога и копыта")
                    {
                        <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="details" data-id="@item2.Name">@item2.Name</a></td>
                        <td align="center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.Email)</td>
                        <td align="center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.data1)</td>
                        <td align="center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.data2)</td>
                        <td align="center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.data3)</td>
                    }
                </tr>
            }
    }
</tbody>
```

В моем представлении не все гладко, лишние ячейки отображаются. Хотя данные выводятся, хотелось бы использовать Bootstrap. Может кто подскажет куда двигаться?

**Правка**

Пытаюсь получить что то похожее на это

[image: группирование строк]

**Сделал пока что так**

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">ФИО</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Должность</th>
                                    <th scope="col">E-mail</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Данные1</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Данные2</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach (var item in Model.Select(x => x.City).Distinct())
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="5"><strong>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item)</strong></td>
                                    </tr>

                                    foreach (var item2 in Model.Where(p => p.City == item))
                                    {
                                        <tr>
                                            @if (item2.company == "Рога и копыта")
                                            {
                                                <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="details" data-id="@item2.DisplayName">@item2.DisplayName</a></td>
                                                <td align="center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.Title)</td>
                                                <td align="center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.Email)</td>
                                                <td align="center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.data1)</td>
                                                <td align="center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.data2)</td>
                                            }
                                        </tr>
                                    }
                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-5.0

Comment: Не понятно, какое именно представление данных хотите получить. Покажите картинкой, например, или табличку нарисуйте.

Comment: `"table table-bordered table-striped"` - вот bootstrap. Какое отношение он имеет к группировке - непонятно.

Comment: Вопрос решён? Если да, опубликуйте ответ. Если нет, отредактируйте вопрос, дополнив его необходимыми сведениями. Покажите класс `Person`. | Откуда в коде взялось `item2`?

Comment: достаточно одного цикла а не двух. когда у вас меняется город, то в цикле выводите дополнительную строку с названием, и запоминаете. не нужно дистинкты выбирать и вложенные селекты делать

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, отредактировал пост

Comment: @teran, Да вы правы